# Changing one list changed the other list

Tags: python

When I changed one list, the other one also changed.

```
a = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
b = list(a)
a[0][0] = 100
print(a)
print(b)
```

When I do this, a is `[[100, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]`. b is also `[[100, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]`

Doing `b = a[:]` doesn't fix it either.

Why does this happen?

Comment: You did a _shallow copy_, but you need a _deep copy_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you did was a shallow copy. The difference between shallow and deep copying is only relevant for compound objects (objects that contain other objects, like lists or class instances):

A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.
A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

What you want to do it to create a whole new object so that one will not interfere with other. Here is how to do a deep copy.

```
import copy

a = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
a[0][0] = 100
print(a)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is because of shallow copying of list `a`, you can do something like this. Make a copy(shallow-copy) of items present inside the list

```
>>> a = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
>>> b = [list(x) for x in a]
>>> a[0][0] = 100
>>> a
[[100, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
>>> b
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
```